# run an application when reboot in Android

Tags: android

I want to run an application automatically when the phone reboot. I have added these lines to my code:

```
public class BootComplete extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    if (intent.getAction().equalsIgnoreCase(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)) {
        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, MyActivity.class);
        context.startService(serviceIntent);
    }
}
```

And I have added these lines to my Manifest :

```
<receiver
        android:name=".BootComplete"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

and it's permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" >
</uses-permission>
```

It works properly when `MyActivity` class contains just some background tasks. For example when I want to turn on a LED. But when I want to play a media (ex. a video) it doesn't work. Just says service has started and doesn't play anything.

How can I fix it? Is there anything that I must add to the code?

Comment: did you use android monitor to see your log cat?

Comment: Why are you calling an Activity a Service?

Comment: @JoxTraex I have found these by searching in Stack. Is there any better way ?

Comment: What? Start activity by calling `startService`. I have never tried it before.

Comment: Why are you using `equalsIgnoreCase` instead of `equals`?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not with your code! It's about android device.

When the device boot up, you receive the broadcast. But pay attention, when you receive that broadcast, the SD CARD is still populating and you can't access it. If that media is on SD card you cant play it.

Also, you should pay attention to something else: if the user install your app in his/her SD card, that broadcast receiver would never trigger.
So, if you want to prevent problem in some devices, in your manifest, choose internal for your install location too.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I don't want to release my app. I just want to have it in my device.And there is no memory card in my device. Is there any way for doing that ?

Comment: Please share your log cat when the receiver called and media did not play.

Answer (score 0):

Do this change in `BroadcastReceiver`:

```
public class BootComplete extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    if (intent.getAction().equalsIgnoreCase(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)) {
        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, MyActivity.class);
        // Change is here...
        serviceInten.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startService(serviceIntent);
    }
}
```

In the manifest:

```
<receiver
        android:name=".BootComplete"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" >
        <intent-filter android:priority="500">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

            <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
        </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

And leave permission as it is.